# Adding an Image to a Navbar and spcing out navbar links

Tags: html, css

Im building a website at the minute and I want to add a logo to my navbar but one that isn't a link, and I also want to have the links in the more spaced out and remove the spaces between the top of the site and the navbar but I don't know how to do it.

this is the navbar HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>BlueBell Park - Homepage</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/home.css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <a class="active" href="Homepage.html">Home</a>
            <a href="Camping.html">Camping & Caravan Site</a>
            <a href="Fishing.html">Fishing</a>
            <a href="About.html">About Us</a>
        </div>




        <script src="JS/Home.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
        #navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #7b85cd;
    }

    #navbar a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
    }

    #navbar a:hover {
         background-color: #543d8d;
         color: white;
        }

    #navbar a.active {
         background-color: #557272;
         color: white;
    }

    .content {
        padding: 16px;
    }

    .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sticky + .content {
        padding-top: 60px;
     }
```

JS:

```
        window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
```

here's an image of the site so you can see what I'm talking about -
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://mycolor.space/img/color-space-logo.png" alt="logo" width="90px">
```

Comment: This worked great however it places the logo on the right of all my links how would I get it to be on the left?

Comment: If you want it to be before the links, you should write the logo before them, if you want the opposite, you should write after the links

Answer (score 2):

You can space out the links in your navbar by increasing the second part of the padding you have stated in your css #navbar a

padding: 14px **16px**;